# Remove duplication under conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I had a dataframe with date information as below, I would like to remove duplicates in code + currentdate with conditions as below:
1) If there is duplicates in ['code','currentdate'], keep the latest startdate which is less than or current date;
2) If there is no duplicates in ['code','currentdate'], keep the original date.
Thanks!

```
>  code        currentdate       startdate            category 
>    a           2018-04-01      2015-04-28         category_z       
>    a           2018-04-01      2015-08-28         category_x     
>    a           2018-04-01      2018-04-17         category_y  
>    a           2018-05-01      2015-04-28         category_z   
>    a           2018-05-01      2015-08-28         category_x   
>    a           2018-05-01      2018-04-17         category_y      
>    b           2018-04-01      2018-08-28         category_x   
>    b           2018-05-01      2018-08-28         category_x  
>    c           2018-04-01      2018-03-17         category_x     
>    c           2018-04-01      2018-04-28         category_y        
>    c           2018-05-01      2018-03-17         category_x     
>    c           2018-05-01      2018-04-28         category_y
```

The expected output would be:

> ```
> >  code        currentdate       startdate            category      
> >    a           2018-04-01      2015-08-28         category_x   
> >    a           2018-05-01      2018-04-17         category_y      
> >    b           2018-04-01      2018-08-28         category_x   
> >    b           2018-05-01      2018-08-28         category_x  
> >    c           2018-04-01      2018-03-17         category_x     
> >    c           2018-05-01      2018-04-28         category_y
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
m=df.duplicated(['code','currentdate'],keep=False)
n=(df[m].sort_values(['code','startdate'],ascending=[True,False])
       .query("startdate<currentdate").drop_duplicates(['code','currentdate']))
pd.concat([df[~m],n]).sort_index()
```

---

```
  code currentdate  startdate    category
0    a  2018-04-01 2015-08-28  category_x
3    a  2018-05-01 2018-04-17  category_y
4    b  2018-04-01 2018-08-28  category_x
5    b  2018-05-01 2018-08-28  category_x
6    c  2018-04-01 2018-03-17  category_x
9    c  2018-05-01 2018-04-28  category_y
```

Comment: Sorry, since there would have several startdate records less than currentdate in the duplicates, I would like to keep the latest one.

Comment: Maybe adding keep='last' ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen I think the expected output is not correct. just edited, please suggest

Comment: @JennyJingYu for the whole group `b` the startdate is greater then current date, why is that in the expected output?

Comment: Just keep the record as it is, since there is no duplicates in group b.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `tail`

```
df.sort_values(['startdate']).groupby(['code','currentdate']).tail(1)
```

Update

```
df['Key']=df.currentdate>=df.startdate
df.sort_values(['startdate']).groupby(['code','currentdate']).apply(lambda x : x if len(x)<=1 else x.loc[x['Key']].tail(1))
Out[380]: 
                    code currentdate   startdate    category    Key
code currentdate                                                   
a    2018-04-01  1     a  2018-04-01  2015-08-28  category_x   True
     2018-05-01  5     a  2018-05-01  2018-04-17  category_y   True
b    2018-04-01  6     b  2018-04-01  2018-08-28  category_x  False
     2018-05-01  7     b  2018-05-01  2018-08-28  category_x  False
c    2018-04-01  8     c  2018-04-01  2018-03-17  category_x   True
     2018-05-01  11    c  2018-05-01  2018-04-28  category_y   True
```

Comment: mmm, you dont get the desired result. I initially thought the 'head' will fix it but tail wont give you the OP requested result. see column 'code' for value 'a' you'll get start date for category_y twice (same start date) where it should be category_y and category_x